# How to see an indication that I have notifications? (on a Mac laptop)

Tags: notifications, monterey

When clicking on the datetime, I see list of notifications, why is nice. I see the latest messages I can act upon. See screencap below.

When I look at the screen, I see the notifications popping up, which is also nice as I can respond accordingly, like reading a new message or run a test after a successful build.

The notification doesn't stay popped up, so it doesn't disturb what I'm doing right now. It's "minimized" after a few seconds to the notifications area I mentioned above.

But, if I look away while new notifications arrive (like talking to someone or having a glass of water) I miss the popped up notification and the animation of them being minimized.

Another way to miss the popped up notifications is to put on the DND (Do Not Disturb).

**The problem is that there's no indication that I have new notifications. How can I tell that I have missed notification without actively opening the notifications list?**

I don't want to actively open the notifications area every 5 minutes just to validate I didn't miss anything. IMO a good UX would show me some indication that there are new notifications...

osx version: Monterey 12.1 (21C52)

Example of an opened notifications area:

[image]

Comment: You can set notifications to persist in [Notifications Settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-notifications-preferences-mh40583/mac) by setting "Alert style" from "Banners" to "Alerts": "Notifications stay on the screen until you dismiss them". Would that work, or is the "Banners" automatic disappearing important to you?

Comment: Are you suggesting that DND should "disturb" you the first time you get a notification?

Comment: JBallin, I'm separating the notifications into 2: Knowing that there are notifications and reading them. I don't want to act on every notification immediately upon arrival but I do want to know that I have new ones.